# VSTO/Redemption - getting NullReferenceException on Outlook application.Session

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-redemption

When trying to access `Globals.ThisAddIn.outlookApplication.Session` I get a NullReferenceException on `application.Session`.

```
Redemption.RDOSession session = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
session.MAPIOBJECT = Globals.ThisAddIn.outlookApplication.Session.MAPIOBJECT;
```

The same add-in works for other users on the same machine. This callback is hit from a click event on a ribbon button in Outlook. The user has a logged in session with Exchange and can interact with Exchange server normally.

Please note I do not need to handle the null reference, I need to know why the Session is null.

Comment: Patrick Hofman this question is not a duplicate, I've searched high and low. I can't post again for 90 minutes, please reactivate this question.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman - this is not a duplicate - the question is why in that particular context outlookApplication.Session is null.

Comment: you might want to avoid tagging your question as c# to avoid having people who do not fully understand the problem from jumping in and closing or downvoting your question.